# Ao clicar no TextField é como se minha tela atualizasse o estado dela

Tags: flutter

Estou iniciando no Flutter, e me deparei com a seguinte situação.

Eu tenho uma Widget Statefull e nele contem um TextField e um Future Builder que cria uma grade com alguns resultados vindo de um json.

Quando o sistema inicia, ele realiza uma consulta a uma API Rest. Os dados são mostrados na tela e o TextField server para consultar nesta API filtrando pelo código informado.

```
utils.buildTextField(
          labelText: 'Presquisa',
          controller: comandaController.edtPesquisa,
          onSubmited: (value) {
            setState(() {
              controle.identificacao = value;
            });
          },
        ),
```

Porem, quando eu clico no TextField para digitar a pesquisa, a tela atualiza, realizando uma consulta na Api sem eu mandar.
Alguém sabe por que isso acontece? Tem como evitar isso?
Neste caso, ele está fazendo uma consulta desnecessária.

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: controle.getControle(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber),
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                  ),
                );
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null) {
                  return CashUtils().notFound('Nenhuma comanda aberta');
                } else {
                  return _createComandaTable(context, snapshot);
                }
            }
          },
        ),

Widget buildTextField(
  {String? labelText,
  TextEditingController? controller,
  bool obscure = false,
  String? errorMessage,
  Function(String)? onChanged,
  Function(String)? onSubmited}) {
return TextFormField(
  cursorColor: Colors.amber,
  controller: controller,
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: labelText,
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
  obscureText: obscure,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return errorMessage;
    }
    return null;
  },
  onFieldSubmitted: onSubmited,
  onChanged: onChanged,
);
```

}

```
Future<Map?> getControle() async {
http.Response response;

if (identificacao == null) {
  response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://11.0.0.102:9000/fb/comanda'),
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': utils.baseAuth()});
} else {
  response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://11.0.0.102:9000/fb/comanda'),
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': utils.baseAuth()},
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{'cd_comanda': identificacao!}));
}

print(response.contentLength);
print(response.body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Fala Gustavo. Poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar o que a função ```getControle()``` retorna? Se puder adicionar também a ```buildTextField``` também seria bastante útil e aumentaria as chances de obter uma resposta. Um abraço.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) da classe `FutureBuilder`:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, [...].
> It must not be created during the State.build [...]. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Traduzindo livremente, isso significa que você não deve *criar* a conexão dentro do `FutureBuilder`. Você fez isso na linha `future: controle.getControle(),`. Quando você faz isso, sempre que essa parte da tela for re-desenhada, a função será chamada de novo e a conexão será resetada.

Existem muitos jeitos de resolver esse problema, mas o mais simples é:

1. Iniciar essa conexão no `initState`.
2. Armazenar seu resultado em uma variável da classe de estado.
3. No `futureBuilder`, use a variável que você armazenou.

No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    conexao = controle.getControle(),; // Passo 1: Chame a função dentro do initState e armazene em uma variável.
  }

late Future<Map?> conexao; // Passo 2: A variável criada.

[...]

body: FutureBuilder<Map?>(
    future: conexao, // Passo 3: Usar no FutureBuilder o future armazenado.
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo, vou fazer isso!

Comment: Amigo, você é god d+ haha. Vlw pela dica, funcionou que é uma beleza! Obrigado.